# Yet another Pythonic range implementation for C++

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I recently had the need to loop from zero to some limit only known at runtime.  Instead of writing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
{
    // Some repetitive thing
}
```

I wanted to write something similar to what I often use in Python and D:

```
for i in range(0, limit):
    # Some repetitive thing

foreach(i; 0 .. limit)
{
    // Some repetitive thing
}
```

So I ended up with the following:

```
#include <iterator>

namespace detail
{
    template< typename T >
    class basic_range
    {
    public:
        explicit basic_range(T const last, int const step = 1)
            : basic_range(T{ 0 }, last, step)
        {}

        explicit basic_range(T const first, T const last, int const step = 1)
            : first{ first, last, step }, last{ last, last, step }
        {}

        basic_range(basic_range const& other) = delete;
        basic_range(basic_range && other) = default;
        basic_range operator=(basic_range const& other) = delete;
        basic_range operator=(basic_range && other) = delete;

    public:
        struct iterator : std::iterator< std::forward_iterator_tag, T >
        {
            explicit iterator(T const from, T const to, int const step = T{ 1 })
                : from{ from }, to{ to }, step{ step }
            {}

            iterator(iterator const& other) = default;
            iterator(iterator && other) = delete;
            iterator operator=(iterator const& other) = delete;
            iterator operator=(iterator && other) = delete;

            T const operator*() const { return from; }

            bool operator==(iterator const& other) const { return from == other.from; }
            bool operator!=(iterator const& other) const { return from != other.from; }

            void operator++()
            {
                from += step;
                check_limit();
            }

        private:
            void check_limit()
            {
                if (step > 0)
                {
                    if (from > to)
                    {
                        from = to;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (from < to)
                    {
                        from = to;
                    }
                }
            }

        private:
            T         from;
            T   const to;
            int const step;
        };

        typedef iterator       iterator;
        typedef iterator const const_iterator;

        const_iterator begin() const { return first; }
        const_iterator end()   const { return last; }

    private:
        const_iterator first;
        const_iterator last;
    };

    template< typename T, bool is_enum = std::is_enum< T >::value >
    struct get_integral_type
    {
        typedef std::underlying_type_t< T > type;
    };

    template< typename T >
    struct get_integral_type< T, false >
    {
        typedef T type;
    };

    template< typename T, bool is_enum = std::is_enum< T >::value >
    using get_integral_type_t = typename get_integral_type< T >::type;
}
```

With some supporting functions to aid in constructing a range:

```
template< typename T >
auto range(T const begin, T const end, int const step = 1)
{
    typedef detail::get_integral_type_t< T > type;

    static_assert(std::is_integral< type >::value,
                  "Only integer-based types allowed!");

    return detail::basic_range< type >{
        static_cast<type>(begin),
        static_cast<type>(end),
        step
    };
}

template< typename T, typename U >
auto range(T const begin, U const end, int const step = 1)
{
    typedef std::common_type_t
    <
        detail::get_integral_type_t< T >,
        detail::get_integral_type_t< U >
    > type;

    static_assert(std::is_integral< type >::value,
                  "Only integer-based types allowed!");

    return detail::basic_range< type >{
        static_cast<type>(begin),
        static_cast<type>(end),
        step
    };
}

template< typename T >
auto reverse_range(T const from, T const to, int const step = -1)
{
    return range(from, to, step);
}

template< typename T, typename U >
auto reverse_range(T const from, U const to, int const step = -1)
{
    return range(from, to, step);
}
```

This allows for syntax very close to the Python version:

```
for(auto const i: range(0, limit))
{
    // Some repetitive task
}
```

I am, so far, pleased with how well it works both forwards and backwards, however, I feel that the iterator implementation is sloppy and, since documentation on correct iterator implementation is hard to come by, I turn to the community to help me further refine this design.  Of course, you are free to pick holes elsewhere.  For example, I should probably check the inputs to the range functions before blindly returning an object that will misbehave...

A more complete example of usage can be found [here](http://ideone.com/A8fv3P) which includes some simple unit tests to help debug the code.  Any insights are appreciated

Comment: What is the advantage? It looks like your version is longer, slower, less versatile, less readable and way more complex than the naive for-loop.

Comment: The advantage is I learn something about manipulating the type system and a little more about iterators.  This isn't intended for production.  Merely a little hobby hacking where I take liberty to indulge thoughts and experiment.  The native for loop will likely always be faster.

Comment: @nwp Most of the stuff is optimized by the compiler. A simple loop (0-100) using `std::cout` differs in only 6 instructions to the "normal" for loop.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Usually the compiler is very good at that sort of stuff, but timing `for(auto i: range(0, 1000000)` against `for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)` my solution runs 0.1s slower :(.  Whether or not that is significant depends on the application, of course.  The point here, is that my solution (at least on Visual Studio 2015) is slower than the traditional for loop.

Comment: @BigDaveDev Yeah, I think that this is because of your check in `check_limit`.

Comment: Doing this for learning purposes is a totally valid reason and deserves a particularly good code review.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I believe you are correct...

Comment: @nwp Have at it! :)

Comment: @BigDaveDev I would try to set `last` so it does align with your step size. Then you won't need to check every time but only once. e.g. `range(0,100,3)` --> set last to `102`. The result will be the same, yet you don't have to check the limits.

Comment: Oh and you might want to change the type of `step` from `int` to `T`.

Comment: At first glance, a great deal of this just seems rather...overdone. For example, is there a real use-case for having the beginning and ending of the range have different types?

Comment: @JerryCoffin if you try to create a range with `range(0, limit)` where `limit` is of, say `unsigned int` type then the template resolution fails for the first instance of range, but matches the second, since 0 is `int`.  `std::common_type_t` then helps to adjust the types to the most compatible and create a `basic_range`.  So yes, I'm afraid there was a use case.    
@SimonKraemer good idea about aligning `last` to step.  That brings basic_range to within 0.05s of the standard for loop :)

Comment: Since C++20, we have `for (int i : view::iota(0, 100))`. For now we can use the Ranges library :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I came up with a solution that should be as fast a "normal" loop. As already discussed your main problem is the `check_limits` function that is called on every iteration.

I removed the check (see `Change 4` comments) and instead added a function to calculate a range that is compatible with the size of `step` (see `Change 1` comments).

This function is now used instead of just using `T last` (see `Change 2` comments).

Also: To prevent someone from messing around with the iterator I made the constructor private and added `basic_range<T>` as friend class (see `Change 3` comments).

```
#include <iterator>

namespace detail
{
    template< typename T >
    class basic_range
    {
    private:

        //Change 1: Calculate end
        static T adjustedLast(T const first, T const last, T const step)
        {
            //Using modulo on signed types is UB
            using UT = typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type;
            UT difference = std::abs(last - first);
            UT stepping = std::abs(step);

            T underflow = T(difference % stepping) * (step / T(stepping));
            if (underflow == 0) return last;

            return last + (step - underflow);
        }

    public:
        explicit basic_range(T const last, T const step = 1)
            : basic_range(T{ 0 }, last, step)
        {}

        explicit basic_range(T const first, T const last, T const step = 1)
            : first{ first, adjustedLast(first, last, step), step }, last{ adjustedLast(first, last, step), adjustedLast(first, last, step), step } //Change 2: use calculated last
        {}

        basic_range(basic_range const& other) = delete;
        basic_range(basic_range && other) = default;
        basic_range operator=(basic_range const& other) = delete;
        basic_range operator=(basic_range && other) = delete;

    public:
        struct iterator : std::iterator< std::forward_iterator_tag, T >
        {
            //Change 3: Make constructor private
            friend class basic_range<T>;

        private: //Change 3: Make constructor private
            explicit iterator(T const from, T const to, int const step = T{ 1 })
                : from{ from }, to{ to }, step{ step }
            {
            }

        public:
            iterator(iterator const& other) = default;
            iterator(iterator && other) = delete;
            iterator operator=(iterator const& other) = delete;
            iterator operator=(iterator && other) = delete;

            T const operator*() const { return from; }

            bool operator==(iterator const& other) const { return from == other.from; }
            bool operator!=(iterator const& other) const { return from != other.from; }

            void operator++()
            {
                from += step;
                //Change 4: Remove check()
            }


            //Change 4: Remove check()

        private:
            T         from;
            T   const to;
            int const step;
        };

        typedef iterator       iterator;
        typedef iterator const const_iterator;

        const_iterator begin() const { return first; }
        const_iterator end()   const { return last; }

    private:
        const_iterator first;
        const_iterator last;
    };

    template< typename T, bool is_enum = std::is_enum< T >::value >
    struct get_integral_type
    {
        typedef std::underlying_type_t< T > type;
    };

    template< typename T >
    struct get_integral_type< T, false >
    {
        typedef T type;
    };

    template< typename T, bool is_enum = std::is_enum< T >::value >
    using get_integral_type_t = typename get_integral_type< T >::type;
}

template< typename T >
auto range(T const begin, T const end, int const step = 1)
{
    typedef detail::get_integral_type_t< T > type;

    static_assert(std::is_integral< type >::value,
        "Only integer-based types allowed!");

    return detail::basic_range< type >{
        static_cast<type>(begin),
            static_cast<type>(end),
            step
    };
}

template< typename T, typename U >
auto range(T const begin, U const end, int const step = 1)
{
    typedef std::common_type_t
        <
        detail::get_integral_type_t< T >,
        detail::get_integral_type_t< U >
        > type;

    static_assert(std::is_integral< type >::value,
        "Only integer-based types allowed!");

    return detail::basic_range< type >{
        static_cast<type>(begin),
            static_cast<type>(end),
            step
    };
}

template< typename T >
auto reverse_range(T const from, T const to, int const step = -1)
{
    return range(from, to, step);
}

template< typename T, typename U >
auto reverse_range(T const from, U const to, int const step = -1)
{
    return range(from, to, step);
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (auto const i : range(0, -100, -3))
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

The new function `adjustedLast` might seem a little bit difficult in the beginning. All it does is to calculate the next step equal or greater than the current `last` in the direction of `step`:

```
//Change 1: Calculate end
static T adjustedLast(T const first, T const last, T const step)
{
    //Using modulo on signed types is UB
    using UT = typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type;
    UT difference = std::abs(last - first);
    UT stepping = std::abs(step);

    T underflow= T(difference % stepping) * (step / T(stepping));
    if (underflow== 0) return last;

    return last + (step - underflow);
}
```

`using UT = typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type;` is used to get the unsigned equivalent of `T` as the function makes use of the modulo operator. Modulo operations on signed types is UB.

Next is to get the difference between `first` an `last` and store it in the unsigned type. This is perfectly fine since `std::abs` will only return positive values. Also we are getting the absolute value of step.

It doesn't matter if we are going from `0` to `1000` in steps of `5` or from `1000` to `0` in steps of `-5`... all we need is if we exactly hit `last` when iterating.

`difference % stepping` will give us this value. e.g. when using `range(0,100,3)` the last value we hit is `99` which is `1` short of `100`.
`difference % stepping` will give us this `1`.

What we need now is the value being signed again in the direction of step. `step / T(stepping)` will return `-1` if `step` is negative and `1` if step is positve.

If there is no underflow `if (underflow== 0)` we can just return the last we were provided with. Otherwise we need to calculate the next last that can be "hit" with `step`. So we use `(step - underflow)` to find the difference we need and add it to `last`.

**Example:**

`adjustedLast(0,100,3)`

- `difference = 100`
- `stepping = 3`
- `underflow = (100%3) * (3/3) = 1 * 1 = 1`
- returns: `100 + (3-1) = 102`

`adjustedLast(0,-100,-3)`

- `difference = 100`
- `stepping = 3`
- `underflow = (100%3) * (-3/3) = 1 * -1 = -1`
- returns: `-100 + (-3-(-1)) = -100 + (-3+1) = -102`

---

Comparing the new code to a normal for loop with the same range actually shows us no difference in compiler instructions:

[`for (int i = 0; i < 100; i+=1)`](http://goo.gl/K6WFUp)

```
std::ctype<char>::do_widen(char) const:
        mov     eax, esi
        ret
main:
        push    r12
        push    rbp
        xor     ebp, ebp
        push    rbx
        jmp     .L6
.L14:
        movsx   esi, BYTE PTR [rbx+67]
.L5:
        mov     rdi, r12
        add     ebp, 1
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::put(char)
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::flush()
        cmp     ebp, 100
        je      .L12
.L6:
        mov     esi, ebp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     r12, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [r12+240+rax]
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .L13
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rbx+56], 0
        jne     .L14
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+48]
        cmp     rax, OFFSET FLAT:std::ctype<char>::do_widen(char) const
        je      .L5
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    rax
        movsx   esi, al
        jmp     .L5
.L12:
        pop     rbx
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
.L13:
        call    std::__throw_bad_cast()
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init()
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
```

[`for (auto const i : range(0, 100))`](http://goo.gl/Q2JPAg)

```
std::ctype<char>::do_widen(char) const:
        mov     eax, esi
        ret
main:
        push    r12
        push    rbp
        xor     ebp, ebp
        push    rbx
        jmp     .L6
.L14:
        movsx   esi, BYTE PTR [rbx+67]
.L5:
        mov     rdi, r12
        add     ebp, 1
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::put(char)
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::flush()
        cmp     ebp, 100
        je      .L12
.L6:
        mov     esi, ebp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     r12, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [r12+240+rax]
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .L13
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rbx+56], 0
        jne     .L14
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+48]
        cmp     rax, OFFSET FLAT:std::ctype<char>::do_widen(char) const
        je      .L5
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    rax
        movsx   esi, al
        jmp     .L5
.L12:
        pop     rbx
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
.L13:
        call    std::__throw_bad_cast()
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init()
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your pointers.  Compiling with -O3 or -Ofast on g++5 with a million iterations actually has the range implementation edge out the for loop.  I ran the benchmark several times and it is quite consistent.  Really cool result with the assembly (I was able to reproduce two sets of identical assembly as well).  Thanks again!